# Python Stripe Payment Gateway

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to charge cards via Python.
However, I cannot get it to work.
according to documentation I can use the test stripe cards
https://stripe.com/docs/testing

However when using one of the test cards, i am getting error

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_y3tPpc4nHFd7Pi: No such token: 4242424242424242
```

Please let me know how I can test. I do not have a stripe account with cards or balances.

```
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc"

a = stripe.Charge.create(
  amount=2000,
  currency="usd",
  source="4242424242424242",
  description="My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is [1]:

```
    # `source` is obtained with Stripe.js; see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges#web-create-token
    stripe.Charge.create(
      amount=2000,
      currency="eur",
      source="tok_visa",  # <-- The tokenized card information not a CC number
      description="My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
    )
```

You need to tokenize the card information using Stripe.js using `createToken()`. [2]

All that being said, the recommended integration path is using PaymentIntents and not Tokens and Charges. [3]

Hope that helps!

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=python

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web

Comment: Thank you so much, createToken python helper works.